# Создавая подкласс от строки надо сделать новую метод append где он будет принимать аргумент и конкатенировать с твоей строкой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Создавая подкласс от строки надо сделать новую метод append где он будет принимать аргумент и конкатенировать с твоей строкой.

Нужно чтоб код вывел 'bootcamppython', но он не работает

```
class Mystring(str):
  def __init__(self, main, add_str=''):
    self.main = main
    self.add_str = add_str

  def append(self, add_str):
    self.main = self.main + self.add_str
    return self.main

str1 = Mystring('bootcamp')
str1.append('python')
```

Comment: В методе `append` должно быть `self.main = self.main + add_str`. И не понятно зачем вам вообще иметь эту `self.add_str`.

Comment: Ещё и `print` по-хорошему тут нужно, а не полагаться, что среда сама вам выведет значение, ну и реализовать `__str__` для класса.